# Debain/Composer can't connect to github(443 and 22)

Tags: github, connection, timeout, debian

Whenever I try to get files from github, I can't get any connection to github. 
I tried with wget and also with composer(different repositorys). The response is always the same: "connection timeout".

Composer error:

```
Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

I've tried following "fix", but it didn't change anything:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

When I run the same commands(wget or composer) on other v-hosts, it's working without problems.

OS: Debian 8(fresh install)
Installed ufw and opened port for https.

Regards

Comment: I think you should ask to the sister site Unix and Linux (unix.stackexchange.com). This seems more a problem of settings then a programmer question (so it is better and easier to get correct answer there).